# How to select a random Image from a directory of images for ImageField in Django model?

Tags: django

I am not being able to select a random image from a directory of random images.

```
def random_img():
    dir_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    files = [content for content in listdir(
        dir_path) if isfile(path_join(dir_path, content))]
 return str(choice(files))
```

I am using this function with:

```
profile_pic = models.ImageField(
        default=random_img(), upload_to="profile_images/")
```

But this is giving issues during migrations

Answer (score 0):

If you want the default image to be *random*, then you should pass a callable, since otherwise, you *evaluate* the function eagerly, and that result is the default. For example:

```
from django.db import models
from os import listdir
import os.path
from os.path import isfile
from os.path import join as path_join
from random import choice

def random_img():
    dir_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    files = [
        content for content in listdir(dir_path)
        if isfile(path_join(dir_path, content))
    ]
    return choice(files)

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default=random_img, upload_to="profile_images/")
```

So we do *not* add brackets to the `random_img`, we do not *call* the function, we pass the function itself, and let Django call it when it needs to select a default value.

The result of `random_img` should be a filepath relative to the `MEDIA_ROOT` (this looks correct here, although if you change settings, it might fail).